# Working on classes for a text based game in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

i'm trying to create a function to raise max hp whenever a stat is increased or decreased.  i have tried changing self.maxHpCalc() player.**  moving the variables = (int) into the orc class in every why i can think of and have been having no luck. depending on how i change it i get self/player have no attribute strength, maxHp    or maxHpCalc is not defined.

```
class player:
    def __init__(self, hp = 1 , maxHp = 1, strength = 4, defense = 5):
        self.hp = hp
        self.maxHp = maxHpCalc()
        self.strength = strength
        self.defense = defense

    def maxHpCalc():
        player.maxHp = player.strength + player.defense

class orc(player):
    def __init__(self, hp, maxHp, strength , defnese):
        super().__init__(hp, maxHp, strength, defense)
print(player.maxHp)
```

everything i change give me player/self has no attribute strength      at the moment

Comment: I have read this but I'm struggling to see a question. Are you just looking for some reassurance that you are doing it right?

Comment: lol yes, for the top section. more or less i was just talking to myself. if it seems right ignore it. mainly i am having issues with all of the def functions at the end. since i want them to be an ever changing variable depending on what the stats are. so i run into errors like "player has no attribute upperStrength"  or maxHPCalc not defined.   as for right now i have a raiseStat() function and have  maxHp = (formula) and that works, but from what i've seen there should be a way to put the function into the class    maxHp = maxHpCalc()    i haven't found a way to make it work.

Comment: Did you try indenting those functions in by one, so they fall under the scope of the class? You can never be sure on here that these kinds of indentation error are not a result of pasting the code into the text box or a genuine error in the original posters code.

Comment: yes moving it doesn't change error code
  File "C:\Users\reede_000\Desktop\gameCode\gamefile\Player.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.maxHp = maxHpCalc()
NameError: name 'maxHpCalc' is not defined

Comment: Instead try `self.maxHp = self.maxHpCalc() `. The method is a property of the class and so must be prefixed with self. Its contrary to many other languages which are able to implicitly include the self/this reference. It's certainly a bit clunky.

Comment: its better to post it in the question. Either remove what you already have or add a section at the bottom, making it clear its an update to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some fixed code, with a small driver program to exercise the classes.

Note the following changes

1. The function `maxHpCalc` should be a bound method, if it is to operate on data contained in a `player` instance. Therefore it should have a `self` parameter and should reference `strength` and `defense` from that self reference.
2. When calling `_maxHpCalc` you should reference `self`. I made it a bound method and it needs an instance to work on. I added an underscore to indicate it's a private method.
3. You should call `maxHpCalc` **after** setting the values of `strength` and `defense`, otherwise they are not defined at the point the function is called.
4. `player.maxHp` makes no sense. `player` is a class and has no static 
   property `maxHp`, you need an instance to access that property. I create an instance and reference that.

code:

```
class player:
    def __init__(self, hp=1, maxHp=1, strength=4, defense=5):
        self.hp = hp
        self.strength = strength
        self.defense = defense
        self.maxHp = self._maxHpCalc()

    def _maxHpCalc(self):
        return self.strength + self.defense

class orc(player):
    def __init__(self, hp, maxHp, strength , defense):
        super().__init__(hp, maxHp, strength, defense)

p = player()
o = orc(1,2,3,4)

print(p.maxHp)
print(o.maxHp)
```

I also have to ask, why include a constructor parameter `maxHp` if you don't use it but calculate it from other parameters?

Comment: adding the underscore seemed to be my main issue. i didn't even know that was something you could add. removing it gives the same errors so that fixes it to workable.
as far as having the maxHp = 1 there was no real purpose for it to be there. i have been messing around with this for days and confused myself on having it there. since i couldn't get the function to work i brute forced it inside of a different function just to tweek my formula and continue on without it crashing
also the print statement gives 9 and 7?   also what is the orc(1,2,3,4) for?

Comment: @Reederboard the underscore should have no bearing on the program, as long as its either present or not present when the function is defined and used. It's just a convention.

Comment: if the underscore is removed it fails:     self.maxHp = self.maxHpCalc()
AttributeError: 'player' object has no attribute 'maxHpCalc'

Comment: Yes if you wish to remove the underscore, you must do it in both places. Where the function is defined and where it is called.