# python, how to make/change a list with lists

Tags: python, list, function

So more or less i am trying to figure this out:

```
a = [1,2]
b = [3,4,5]
c = [6,7,8,9]

z = [a,b,c]

def raiseInt():
    x = 0    

    for int in z:
        a[x] + 1
        b[x] + 1
        c[x] + 1
```

I'm trying to increase every int in every list by 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple way to do this

```
a = [1,2]
b = [3,4,5]
c = [6,7,8,9]

z = [a,b,c]

def raiseInt():

    for L in z:
        for i in range(len(L)):
            L[i] +=1

print(z)
raiseInt()
print(z)
```

output

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
[[2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Iterate over the lists in `z` and then iterate for a number of times equal to the lists length and increment each element.

You could certainly improve your function by passing the lists to be operated on in as a parameter. This would make your function more generally useful, as it is, it can only operate on that one list called `z`.

Comment: this looks like the simplest way to do it.  still isn't working correctly for me but i'm guessing i'm doing something else wrong. i have these variables in a sub class. a, b c have been in there and worked fine, so i added the list z
and the 'def raiseInt()' and i get an    error:   name raiseInt not defined

Comment: as a better example of what i'm doing i had another question post which will have alot more detail in some of the stuff i'm trying to do. all my defs don't work  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43482829/working-on-classes-for-a-text-based-game-in-python

Answer (score 1):

I will try to make my code self-explanatory. Note the name of each object

```
a = [1,2]
b = [3,4,5]
c = [6,7,8,9]

z = [a,b,c]

def raiseInt(list_to_increase_by_1):
    #x = 0 we may actually do not need to assign this variable.    

    for sublist in list_to_increase_by_1:
        for index_of_element, element in enumerate(sublist):
            sublist[index_of_element] += 1
    return list_to_increase_by_1


print raiseInt(z)
```

#### best practice related details

As you can see from Moinuddin Quadri's comments, I do not use the variable (iteratively assigned) `element`. In this case, the convention is about naming it `_`, so as to explicit that tha variable is actually not used.Which thus turns the code into

```
def raiseInt(list_to_increase_by_1):
    for sublist in list_to_increase_by_1:
        for index_of_element, _ in enumerate(sublist):
            sublist[index_of_element] += 1
    return list_to_increase_by_1
```

#### more best practice related details

As can be read from Paul Ronney's comment

> [strictly doing as above] is contrary to python best practice, that any in place modifying function returns None. It should do one or the other and if the choice is to return it should return a copy and leave the original intact

Thus, folowing this comment implies to define `raiseInt` as an in place modifying function, as follows

```
def raiseInt(list_to_increase_by_1):
    for sublist in list_to_increase_by_1:
        for index_of_element, _ in enumerate(sublist):
            sublist[index_of_element] += 1
```

I.e. with the function returning `None`

Comment: I do not see the usage of `enumerate` here. All you are using is index, why not use `range` instead? :)

Comment: If you do insist on using enumerate, then the `element` variable would be better expressed as `_`.

Comment: @Moinuddin Quadri, Paul Rooney  You are rigth. It is all about pedagogy.

Comment: Well, if enumerate is insisted to use, I'll go with `sublist[index_of_element] = element  + 1`. + 1 from me for your answer

Comment: My issue with this solution (aside from the overly verbose variable names) is that it not only returns the updated list but also mutates it in place. This is contrary to python best practice, that any in place modifying function returns `None`. It should do one or the other and if the choice is to return it should return a copy and leave the original intact.

Comment: i'm pretty new to coding, so i don't know all the special function names or just coding vocab in general. are sublist, index_of_element, and enumerate just random variables put in?

Answer (score 0):

```
def raiseInt():
    for v in z:
        for i in range(len(v)): 
            v[i] += 1;
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is a valid Python syntax? PS: Not a downvoter